# Why do threads through a loop give an error when with Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executor

The sample code is taken from the Java Philosophy 2015 book and it used Java SE5/6. I used JDK11, maybe this code is not suitable for the new version, but why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) { 
        exec.execute(new LiftOff2());
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task LiftOff2@5f205aa rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d86b085[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:825)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1355)
    at Runnable_p897.main(Runnable_p897.java:8)
```

Comment: The code as shown will (or should, I haven't verified it) also fail in Java 5 and Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation of `ExecutorService::shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()):

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, **but no new tasks will be accepted**. ...